# Why does MongoDB create _ids as objects?

Tags: database, mongodb

The _ids that are generated by MongoDB are always in this form: `ObjectId("5f1b0e51b931af765f21edd4")`

If the main reason for creating the _id column is to have something to uniquely identifies a document why is the generated _id format not simply in this form `"5f1b0e51b931af765f21edd4`.

I don't know if I'm right, but also I suspect that the first format occupies more space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The _ids that are generated by MongoDB are always in this form: ObjectId("5f1b0e51b931af765f21edd4")

Not at all. Ids generated by MongoDB are [12-byte byte sequences](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/objectid.rst#specification). `mongo` shell uses the rendering `ObjectId("xxx")` to indicate that the value is stored as a 12-byte ObjectId and not as a 24-byte string, which is what `"5f1b0e51b931af765f21edd4"` is.

> I don't know if I'm right, but also I suspect that the first format occupies more space.

As stored by the server, ObjectId occupies less space than a hex string you see on your screen (half as much, in fact). To convey this compact storage, the *rendering* of an ObjectId occupies more space on your screen.

Comment: Well explained, so it's safe to say that ObjectId is more efficient than it's counterpart hex string right?

Comment: This is probably true in most cases, but if you for example create objectids from strings and then compare objectids it may be more efficient to simply compare the strings. So depends on exact details.

Answer (score 1):

[`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) is a special type in Mongo. It is not like a normal object/document and only takes up 12-bytes. The `ObjectId("24-character-hex-string")` is just its human-readable notation.

A 24-character string takes up at least 24-bytes, and if we look up the [bson spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html), stores an additional 4-bytes for length and 1-byte for a null terminator, so 29-bytes total.